# How to add the List-Unsubscribe header correctly?

Tags: php, email

I'm using Postfix mail server on a LAMP stack. I use phpmailer to send my mail. I recently noticed that major ISP's have added support for the "List-Unsubscribe" header. according to Hotmail, live automatically adds a

> You're subscribed to this mailing list. Unsubscribe

I noticed this when checking my Facebook mail. So when I examined the Facebook headers I noticed this line

```
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsub+engage_digest_email@unsubscribe.facebook.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: ZuckMail [version 1.00]
X-Facebook-Camp: engage_digest_email
X-Facebook-Notify: engage_digest_email; mailid=523199eG1fe9e7abG0Gd4
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsub+engage_digest_email@unsubscribe.facebook.com>
Errors-To: update+pmhd_um@facebookmail.com
X-FACEBOOK-PRIORITY: 1
```

So with my phpmailer setup I added the addCustomHeader() function.

```
$x = new PHPMailer();
$x->From = "support@veepiz.com";
$x->FromName = "Veepiz Support";
$x->AddAddress($o->emailaddress,$o->toname);
$x->AddReplyTo("support@veepiz.com", "Veepiz Support");
$x->WordWrap = 80;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
$x->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML
$x->IsSMTP();
$x->Host = "veepiz.com";
$x->Username = 'support@veepiz.com';
$x->Password = 'xxxxxxxx';                
$x->Subject = $o->subject;
$x->Body    = $o->content."\n\n<span style='color:white'>Forgotten your password? go to <a href='http://www.veepiz.com/forgot.php'>http://www.veepiz.com/forgot.php</a></span>";
$x->Body    = str_replace("\r", "\n", wordwrap($x->Body,80));
$x->AltBody = $o->plain_text;
$x->AltBody = str_replace("\r", "\n", wordwrap($x->AltBody,80));
$x->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe@veepiz.com?subject=Unsubscribe>, <http://www.veepiz.com/unsubscribe.php?unsubscribeid=$ox->id>");
```

Now when I send my mail I get this in my mail headers...

```
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe@veepiz.com?subject=Unsubscribe>,<http://www.veepiz.com/unsubscribe.php?unsubscribeid=1>
```

It seems phpmailer is adding this header and it conforms to the rfc http://www.list-unsubscribe.com/

But in Hotmail I don't get the component showing that i've subscribed to blah blah mailing list unsubscribe

> You're subscribed to this mailing list. Unsubscribe

Comment: i cant see any other headers from facebook saying its a list. ive editted post @Zoredache

Comment: What happens if you add only the http url?  Or list it first?

Comment: And look really close at [RFC 2369](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2369).

Comment: @mailq i copied an example from that link List-Subscribe: <http://www.host.com/list.cgi?cmd=sub&lst=list>,
         <mailto:list-manager@host.com?body=subscribe%20list>

Comment: @Zoredache ive tried with email and http url alone and hotmail doesnot add that component.... im i using the phpmailer addCustomHeader function well?   public function AddCustomHeader($custom_header) {
    $this->CustomHeader[] = explode(':', $custom_header, 2);
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you should ask Hotmail. They probably show the component only for trusted newsletters or senders. Who told you that they show this for any mail containing the "List-Unsubscribe:" header.

This header can be used by Phishers and Spammers to make a mail more serious. There is a good chance that Hotmail only accepts these headers from trusted sites.

Comment: And probably the Spam outbreak from your IP in the beginning of October still echoes back to you.

Comment: thx a lot mailq